# HAML Inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, haml

I am new to haml and want to do some inheritance, but I don't know whether it is possible with haml or not.

I have 2 separate haml files as below

```
=== file1.haml

%p

  This is haml1


=== file2.haml

%h1

  This is haml2
```

*** I want to have a `file.haml` which inherit from `file1.haml` and `file2.haml`.

Is it possible to do it with haml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could turn file1.haml and file2.haml to partials (i.e. _file1.haml, _file2.haml) then use the render function in file.haml, for example in file.haml:

```
%p
  =render(:partial => "file1")
%p
  =render(:partial => "file2")
```

Answer (score 0):

[In my implementation](http://w2tags.heroku.com) it can, and the behavior just like Textmate did, you create some bundle of snipt code and use when you need it to make it DRY